# write chars into DB with correct character-set

Tags: c#, oracle

I met a problem writing Chinese characters into an Oracle database. Here's some information for your reference.

1. Environment: Oracle 8

   ```
   select userenv('language') form dual;
   ```

   returns

   ```
   American.America.UTF8
   ```
2. Developing:

   ```
   .NET2/C#
   ```
3. Client characterset:

   ```
   gb2312
   ```

I simply test write value into the table manually, the result is correct and should be as the following:

```
VALUE: 朋友        //chinese word means 'friend'
DUMP: 197,243,211,209 //caculated by Oracle dump() function
```

Using code to write, code snap as following:

```
Encoding def = Encoding.Default;
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] bytes = def.GetBytes("朋友")；
//For debug
//string debug = "";
//foreach(byte b in bytes)
//   debug += b.ToString() + " ";
//Debug.WriteLine(debug); //That will display 197,243,211,209 as the same as the Dump value mentioned
string value = utf8.GetString(bytes);
//I also try, string value = utf8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(def,utf8,bytes))
string sql = String.Format("UPDATE T SET C='{0}' WHERE...",value);
//execute the sql...
```

After that, the value stored in the DBMS is not right, both value and it's dump result.

Comment: What is the database character set?  `SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'`

Comment: Hello,Justin. NLS_CHARECTERSET & NLS_NCHAR_CHARECTSET are UTF8

Comment: i am not familar with Oracle, but in Sql Server you need the N-Prefix if you want unicode. Maybe worth a try?

Comment: Thanks Snoopy.But it doesn't work.Just return 'ora-12704 characterset mismatch'.

Comment: Or does someone know whether could I write raw binary data into a vachar2 type column?

Comment: What is the value stored in the database? You say it is wrong, could you show us what you get back?

Comment: @No. Do not use varchar2 for raw binary. Use "raw" for raw binary: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76965/c10datyp.htm#4147

Answer (score 1):

```
Decimal Hexadecimal Binary
197     c5          1100 0101
243     f3          1111 0011
211     d3          1101 0011
209     d1          1101 0001
```

Looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design) We see that 197 is the first byte of a two byte sequence, 243 is the first byte of a four byte sequence, 211 is the first byte of a two byte sequence, 208 is the first byte of a two byte sequence. That is not valid UTF-8. Could you tell us what the unicode code points for the two characters 朋友 are?

**EDIT** Ah, GB2313, c5f3 is Unicode code point u+670b. And d3d1 is u+53cb. (Found using converter at http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/convexp?conv=ibm-1383_P110-1999&ShowLocales&s=ALL#ShowLocales)

Double check the client character set that the Oracle client is using. What I have seen (on Oracle 10gR2) is that if the Oracle's client has the same character encoding as the database server, then the characters will not be translated (because they are the same character set) but they will not be validated. It appears that they were the same at the time of the manual insert and the GB2313 values were inserted for the characters you wanted, which is invalid inside the DB, since it is utf8.

Note, Oracle's "utf8" character set is not full modern UTF-8, but instead CESU-8. Not an issue in this case, since these characters sit on the Basic Multilingual Plane, and have the same encoding in UTF-8 and CESU-8. The earliest reference I could find was for Oracle 8i: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76966/appa.htm#971460.

Comment: Hi Shannon, very thank your awesome answer. I use the following code to test under your help. Could you please advise how I could to complete the function I want using C#? <br/>`#ruby-code
str = "朋友"
str.each_codepoint do |cp|
  print 'U+%4X' % cp,' '
end 
puts
str.each_byte {|b| print b,' '} //result:U+670B U+53CB `
230 156 139 229 143 139

Comment: No. I don't know enough C# to help on that end. Also, what values are getting stored using what you have now? They may be the valid UTF-8 for the code points in question.